# Minimizing the risk of losing save data when playing offline

Tags: steam

I play several of my Steam games in Offline Mode on a regular occasion. However, none of the save data for these games is managed by the Steam Cloud. Now, I've been thinking about playing some Steam Cloud games offline (Payday 2, for example). What do I do to minimize save data loss, preferably avoid it entirely, and still play my games offline?

Comment: To clarify: you're worried about your offline saves being overwritten by the cloud saves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you play the game in offline mode, make sure before you go offline that you have the latest synchronized data, then when you're going to play it offline, just play it. Once you go back online, if Steam prompts you that there is a "data predicament", simply choose the local version of the data. If you choose the data from the cloud, it will delete your local data (what you saved in offline mode) and replace it with the cloud data. So just don't choose cloud data, and you should have absolutely no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

If you play a Steam Cloud game offline, it will behave exactly like a non-Steam Cloud game. Games will still save locally, and nothing will sync to the Steam Cloud.

If you want to take advantage of the Steam Cloud, you will need to have Steam not be in offline mode.

If you really do wish to use Offline Mode, and also sync your saves to the Steam Cloud, the best available option is probably going to be to use Offline Mode most of the time. Sny time you want to sync your saves to the Cloud, put Steam in Online Mode temporarily, launch the game<sup>Note 1</sup>, and then exit. Steam should then trigger a sync.<sup>Note 2</sup> If you ever lose your save data, then the Steam Cloud will have a backup of it. To retrieve the backup, just go into Online Mode, and on launch, Steam should notice that the Cloud version is newer than what's on your system, and prompt you to download it.

<sub>Note 1: When launching the game to sync save files up to Steam Cloud, it may complain about the two versions not matching. You will almost certainly want to choose the newer files if it prompts you.</sub>

<sub>Note 2: It may or may not simply sync after loading and exiting. Some games specifically require save files to be marked as using the Steam Cloud, for example.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the cloud (for the game or as a whole) will minimize the risk of it overwriting your newer local save. However, cloud usually asks which version to use when the backup doesn't match the local save.

In order to *totally* minimize the risk of save data loss, you should use cloud, update it frequently by launching the game in online mode **and** take local backups in case something goes wrong with cloud.